# Query return no result

Tags: database

I have some database like this.

```
date       name  closed
2017-01-10 room1 0
2017-01-11 room2 1
2017-01-12 room3 0
```

I want to get all the records if in column **closed** all the value is 0. If any one value is 1, I don't want to show all the record.

How can I make some query to do that ?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM availability a 
WHERE a.closed = 0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show all the records in the table, only if all records in availability have the closed value = 0

```
select *
from availability
where 0 = (
select sum( a.closed )
from availability a
)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it works, could you please mark as answer (just in-case someone else requires help?)